Adding types to formik form field custom component resulting in error: Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string'
I'm new with TypeScript, and trying to implement it in past project as an exercise.
I've reached dead-end trying to add types to formik form field custom component, where the is an error Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'. when trying to pass value to the component.
FormField component should be used for multiple forms, so I cannot strictly define type of object used in useFormikContext(), and used generic type T instead.
Form:
interface IPerson {
  firstName: string;
}

<Form (...)>
  <FormField<IPerson> name='firstName' type='text'/>
</Form>

FormField:
interface IFormField {
  inputName: string;
  inputType: string;
}

export default function FormField<T>({ inputName, inputType }: IFormField) {
  const { values } = useFormikContext<T>();

  return (
    <input
      type={inputType}
      value={values[inputName as keyof T]} //'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.
      name={inputName}
    />
  );
}


Working FormField component, but with JavaScript:
export default function FormField({ inputName, inputType }) {
  const { values } = useFormikContext();

  return (
    <input
      type={inputType}
      value={values[inputName]}
      name={inputName}
    />
  );
}

My question is how to make it working with typescript?

You can constrain the type of inputName to be only the keys of T for which T[inputName] can be passed to <input>
type SupportsInput<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: P extends string | number | readonly string[] | undefined ? T[P] : never;
}

interface IFormField<T> {
  inputName: keyof SupportsInput<T>;
  inputType: string;
}

export default function FormField<T>({ inputName, inputType }: IFormField<T>) {
  const { values } = useFormikContext<T>();

  return (
    <input
      type={inputType}
      value={values[inputName]}
      name={inputName as string}
    />
  );
}

